# Send data to Frontend(Angular JS) from backend (Java/Jersey/REST)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, jersey

In my application, I want to send data from backend which is developed in `Java` to the Frontend which is developed in `AngularJS`.

Here, backend can be considered as a Server which will get the data from number of clients. What I want is that whenever the server receives the data, it should forward that data to the frontend, so that the UI can be updated accordingly. I don't want to go for long polling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may be thinking of this backwards. You could write a script in angular so that whenever the page with data is going to be loaded, it will hit your API and update the page accordingly.

Comment: The page which will display the information is most of the time loaded . . its a monitoring application. I don't want to send request to backend everytime that page is loaded or periodically . . that's why I am searching for something that can send request from backend to frontend

Answer (score -1):

Your problem sounds like you are looking for something like this:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

Comment: I am looking into this . . I'll let you know if it works for me . .Thanks for the link